# Import error when debugging youtube-dl in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, module, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a new extractor for youtube-dl. First I want to debug the `__main__.py` to get to know the tool, but I cannot debug using VS Code. Here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["a_youtube_video"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My breakpoint is set in the `__main__.py`, which looks like this:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Execute with
# $ python youtube_dl/__main__.py (2.6+)
# $ python -m youtube_dl          (2.7+)

import sys

if __package__ is None and not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    # direct call of __main__.py
    import os.path
    path = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(path)))

import youtube_dl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube_dl.main() # Breakpoint here
```

The error I'm facing is the `import youtube_dl` line, it reports that there's no module named `youtube_dl`. What am I missing here?

Edit: I've just found a way to debug it. It said right in the comments of the `__main__.py`: From 2.7, the program must be run as a module. However I still don't understand this module thing.

Comment: To add a new extractor, you want to clone https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl project and debug it. see developer instruction https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#developer-instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a "Python: Module" debug configuration. There you will see a `"module"` key in your configuration which you can specify as appropriate to use `__main__` (i.e. I don't' know if there's a top-level `__main__.py` or if its in the package which changes what needs to be specified).

Comment: I already found it, module debug configuration. Thanks for your enthusiasm!